# How can I get the Id of my radio button group?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a number of radio button groups, called `Properties`. A property can be things like "colour", "size", "height", and so on. The properties have options. For "colour", the options could be "Red", "Blue", and so on. When I'm posting my form, I'm able to read the `Id` for each individual radio button, but I haven't been able to access the group-`Id`s.

I'm rendering the properties like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Properties.Count(); i++)
{
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <strong>@Model.Properties[i].Label</strong><br />
        @foreach (var option in Model.Properties[i].Options)
        {
            <label style="font-weight:unset;">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Properties[i].SelectedRadioOption, option.Id, new { id = Model.Properties[i].Id })
                @option.Value
                @Model.Properties[i].Unit
            </label>
            <br />
        }
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Properties[i].SelectedRadioOption)
    </div>
}
```

This produces HTML like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <strong>Size</strong><br />
    <label style="font-weight:unset;">
        <input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Selected property field is required." id="7012" name="Properties[0].SelectedRadioOption" type="radio" value="7025" />
        34 - 36
    </label>
    <br />
    <label style="font-weight:unset;">
        <input id="7012" name="Properties[0].SelectedRadioOption" type="radio" value="7026" />
        37 - 39
    </label>
    <br />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Properties[0].SelectedRadioOption" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>                                
</div>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <strong>Colour</strong><br />
    <label style="font-weight:unset;">
        <input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Selected property field is required." id="7013" name="Properties[1].SelectedRadioOption" type="radio" value="7029" />
        Black
    </label>
    <br />
    <label style="font-weight:unset;">
        <input id="7013" name="Properties[1].SelectedRadioOption" type="radio" value="7036" />
        Pink
    </label>
    <br />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Properties[1].SelectedRadioOption" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

This is the section in my controller's POST-method where I iterate through the `Properties`:

```
List<PropertyOptionForProduct> propertyOptions = new List<PropertyOptionForProduct>();
if (VMProduct.Properties != null)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < VMProduct.Properties.Count(); i++)
    {
        propertyOptions.Add(new PropertyOptionForProduct
        {
            ProductId = VMProduct.Id,
            ProductPropertyId = VMProduct.Properties[i].Id, // <-- This is always 0!
            ProductPropertyOptionId = (int)VMProduct.Properties[i].SelectedRadioOption
        });
    }
}
```

If I select "Black" on the "Colour"-property, the object looks like this:

```
PropertyOptionForProduct
{
    ProductId = 17008,
    ProductPropertyId = 0, // <-- Why not 7013?
    ProductPropertyOptionId = 7025
}
```

The correct value for `ProductPropertyId` in the above example should be 7013, which is the `id`-value on the radio button tag.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I'm a noob.

All I needed to add to make it work was this line of razor-code in the view:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Properties[i].Id)
```

Now I can access the value of `Properties[i].Id` in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

The format of what is posted back from a html `<form>` will be (for example) `name1=value1&name2=value2` this maps to the name and the value field of your checked radiobuttons. Your code might for example example generate this post `Properties[0].SelectedRadioOption=7026&Properties[1].SelectedRadioOption=7036`.

The server has no idea about the id attribute in your radiobutton html. The id field is not included in the post unless you alter the post (using javascript) before it is sent. So either you need to include all identifiers in the value field perhaps separated like `value="1243;34534"` or you need to use javascript to include the id in the post data before it is posted.